# Perl Imager module support on Windows (ActiveState version)

Tags: perl, activestate

I'm attempting to use **Imager (0.94)** image manipulation module on Windows with ActiveState Perl (5.12.3). Attempting to read or write JPEG, GIF or PNG files I get some varation of this message:

```
format 'jpeg' not supported - formats bmp, ico, pnm, raw, sgi, tga available for reading
```

When switching to BMP format everything works as expected.

So, given that the Imager module from ActiveState does not seem to include the required libraries (DLLs?) required to read and write any useful formats Does anyone know of an alternate source of a PPM package that has whatever is required for this module to work correctly on Windows?

Comment: Just a hint that could be useful: try to look at [this](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/jpeg.htm) (jpeg for Windows)

Comment: I suppose I could locate the missing libraries or compile from source, but I eventually gave up and installed Image::Magick. I was just wondering if there was a PPM package out there somewhere that could easily be installed with the required libraries included, but I guess that is not the case.

Comment: Did you try just to add the jpeg62.dll to other provided DLLs? (I don't know if it works, chances are low, but who knows; just wondering if this works)